# SVN ignoring a subfolder previously commited

Tags: svn

After trying all sort of combinations I can't find a way to ignore my previously commited media files.

Here is my structure and what I did :

folders :

```
 /www
    /app
    /media
    /skin
    /....
```

I what to ignore the media folder and all it's subfolders.

I 've set the svn:ignore property to "media" for the folder "/www" and I've commited "/www"

But after doing a "svn st" on "/www" I have thousands of "?" lines for all my media files that are not in SVN...

```
?       media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x160/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/5/050565.jpg
?       media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x160/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/5/050596.jpg
?       media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x160/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/5/050642_c.jpg
?       media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x160/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/5/050643_c.jpg
?       media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x160/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/5/050645_c.jpg
?       media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x160/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/5/050647.jpg
?       media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x160/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/5/050648_c.jpg
?       media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x160/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/5/050806.jpg
?       media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/180x160/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/0/5/050814.jpg
```

What did I miss ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the code from svn server and then

```
  svn delete folder --keep-local
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep them in SVN? If so, you want the [sparse checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) feature where you can tell SVN to track a partial directory structure in your working copy (ie you only checkout part of the repo).

Comment: No they only pollute the svn repo. I deleted them from previously using "svn rm https://..../media"